# cant get my background-color show

Tags: css

```
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.nav_wrapper{
  width:18%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:cornflowerblue;
}

.resposive-page{
  width:82%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:deeppink;
}
```

how do i make my container is 100% height and width same as body ? and 18% on nav_wrapper , 82% on reposive-page without using and px ? why my background-color wont show.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/cb8ctkfo/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `html`, `body` and `container` need to have a height of !00% set.

Then float the inner elements

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
}

.nav_wrapper{
  width:18%;
  height:100%;
  float: left;
  background-color:cornflowerblue;
}

.resposive-page{
  width:82%;
  height:100%;
  float: left;
  background-color:deeppink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="nav_wrapper"></div>
<div class="resposive-page"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank alot ~ appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Your divs aren't showing up because they are empty. Place a non breaking space character in them, and then they will render. Like so:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `height: 100vh;` for your `.nav-wrapper` and `.resposive-page` instead of `height: 100%;`. Then add a `float: left;` to your`.nav-wrapper` and `.resposive-page` as well.

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
}

.nav_wrapper{
  width:18%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:cornflowerblue;
  float: left;
}

.resposive-page{
  width:82%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:deeppink;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="nav_wrapper"></div>
<div class="resposive-page"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're referring to? 
https://jsfiddle.net/cb8ctkfo/3/

The `height` attribute isn't used well as a percentage because unlike the `width` property, it is based on its content. When you use percentage with a `width` attribute it is independent of its content, assuming it's a `block` element.

But this gives you a step in the right direction.